# Difference between DynamoDb PutItem vs UpdateItem?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Based on DynamoDb documentation why would anyone use `updateItem` instead of `putItem`?

---

- `PutItem` - Writes a single item to a table. If an item with the same primary key exists in the table, the operation replaces the item. For calculating provisioned throughput consumption, the item size that matters is the larger of the two.
- `UpdateItem` - Modifies a single item in the table. DynamoDB considers the size of the item as it appears before and after the update. The provisioned throughput consumed reflects the larger of these item sizes. Even if you update just a subset of the item's attributes, `UpdateItem` will still consume the full amount of provisioned throughput (*the larger of the "before" and "after" item sizes*).

Answer (score 230, accepted):

The main difference between the two is, `PutItem` will **Replace** an entire item while `UpdateItem` will **Update** it.

Eg.

I have an item like:

```
userId = 1
Name= ABC
Gender= Male
```

If I use `PutItem` item with

```
UserId = 1
Country = India
```

This will replace Name and Gender and now new Item is UserId and Country.
While if you want to update an item from `Name = ABC` to `Name = 123` you have to use `UpdateItem`.

You can use `PutItem` item to update it but you need to send all the parameters instead of just the Parameter you want to update because it Replaces the item with the new attribute(Internally it Deletes the item and Adds a new item)

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Harshal , In my use case, I always overwrite all the fields for each unique (partitionKey+sortKey) . I was wondering if I can mitigate some performance overhead using updateItem instead of PutItem . But seems like ,internally they works the same way  (Internally it Deletes the item and Add new item) .

Comment: Any idea on performance implications using `update` instead of `put`?

Comment: @AmirKarimi, Basically Put will do 3 operations internally FindKey-> Delete -> Add and update will do FindKey -> Update so I think update will be faster

Comment: Note: In the above example, if we do PUT item with "UserId = 1
Country = India", it will delete the attribute "Name= ABC". Like Harshal Bulsara mentioned, it will delete it, then add the new Item

Comment: Are you able to run UpdateItem when there is no item found and it will insert it?

Comment: I haven't tried that. Logically that should not work though.

Answer (score 36):

`PutItem` overwrites the whole item (all attributes) with the new version being passed while `UpdateItem` will only **Update** the passed attributes

**Performance**: `PutItem` may affect on the performance if you overwrite the entire item so often as it involves more operations than `UpdateItem` FindItem, DeleteOldVersion, and AddNewVersion

**From cost prospective, it is different as well:**

AWS calculates the cost based on used read/write capacity units that are completely tied to the size of the item being overwritten/updated.

In case of `PutItem`, the size will be the larger of the new and old versions of the item. For example, replacing a 2 KB item with a 1 KB, It will consume 2 WCUs however subsequent requests will only use 1 WCU. so if you're overwriting so often and the size of the item changes heavily that will calculate always the larger version of the item and affects on the cost.

In case of modifying items using `UpdateItem`, the size includes all of the item’s pre-existing attributes, not the larger version like `PutItem` :) but also not just the ones being added or updated :(

Comment: From cost perspective, isn't it frustrating? I want to append a little data on a list attribute. Why would I consume writing capacity of whole item? Is there a work-around for this case? Let's say, the data I append is like 50byte. And my item is 200 kb. What is the correct approach to make it with minimum WCU?

Comment: @neiloth You may want to ask that as a separate question, but typically for a list of items with frequent append operations, you'd want to make that data its own table with each append as a put, not a single record that needs to keep getting updated.

Comment: @GrandOpener no need for new table, just new object with dedicated pk/sk namespace for the list items. 200kb is huge item. i would consider splitting it to multiple unless you really need all of it for all reads & you actually update most/all of it during writes. which sounds like not the case here.

Answer (score 4):

Slight correction in the above answer: Even the update item API takes the larger of the two item sizes(pre-update and post-update) into consideration. See documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html#ItemSizeCalculations.Writes).

Comment: Please add this as a comment. We don't know which answer you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I think we can define the only benefit of the updateItem over the putItem like this:

1. With putItem, we are only sending the updated attributes over the network, not the entire item, so you can save network bandwidth and network transfer time.
2. You don't need to "get" the entire item before updating an attribute, so you may be able to avoid the "get" in the first place if you already know beforehand what you want to update without having a copy of the item locally. If you're only, say, adding a date attribute to an item, you don't need to "get" the whole item to do that, your code is simpler and you save the read capacity unit(s) to get the item before updating.
3. If network bandwidth or speed is not an issue and you already have the entire item locally already, there is no benefit at the level of the database (including costs) to only update the certain attributes than simply put (and overwrite) the item as a whole. In python, this means that if you already have a dict of the item, you simply change the dict and dump it back into the table using putItem. Because of this, I never use updateItem if I have the item locally, because there's no difference in cost and that code is a lot more elegant and easier to read.

Apologies if this is completely wrong, but that's how I interpret the docs.