# Which is faster in performance putItem v/s UpdateItem in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using transaction (transact write) which has the series of following operations:-

1. Updating primary key -  **delete operation**
2. adding a new record with the updated primary key:- This actually means a new record so here I am confused whether to use put or update as both will insert [a new record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) according to docs.

will the performance be the same in this case?

Note i am not looking for the difference in terms of how they perform as mentioned in this question [Difference between DynamoDb PutItem vs UpdateItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43667229/13126651)

Comment: In terms which is faster depends on your total item size and the size of the attribute you want to update. Updating a small sized attribute in a large item will be faster because there is less network latency.

Comment: in both the operation item size will be same