# Optimizing DynamoDB Operations for Multiple Record Types: Inserts and Updates

Tags: python, multithreading, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I need to process two types of JSON files and store their details into AWS DynamoDB. Let's consider type A and type B files. Type A includes process ID, start date, client ID, and process type, while type B includes process ID, end date, process type, and client ID. The only difference between them is the presence of start date in type A and end date in type B.

The attributes of my DynamoDB table are process ID, start date, end date, and client ID.

For instance:

Type A record: 'process_id': 1234, 'start_date': '2023-08-01', 'client_id': 'C-1', process_type: 'A'

Type B record: 'process_id': 1234, 'end_date': '2023-08-10', 'client_id': 'C-1', process_type: 'B'

I will store these records as a single entry in the DynamoDB table:

'process_id': 1234, 'start_date': '2023-08-01', 'end_date': '2023-08-10', 'client_id': 'C-1'

Depending on which type comes first, I will insert that record. If another record with the same process ID and a different type comes later, I will update the date accordingly. For example:

If type A records come first, I will insert the record with process ID, start date, and client ID (only missing end date). Later, if type B data with the same process ID 1234 arrives, I will update the end date instead of creating a new entry. Similarly, if type B comes first, I will insert with process ID, end date, and client ID (start date only missing). I will update the start date when a record with the same process ID arrives. I don't know which type of record will arrive first.

```
Type A: `{'process_id': 1234, 'start_date': '2023-08-01', 'client_id': 'C-1'}` // Type A arrived first, so INSERT the record without the `end_date`. 
Type B: {'process_id': 1234, 'end_date': '2023-08-10', 'client_id': 'C-1'}` // When Type B arrives with the `end_date` value, UPDATE the record to include 'end_date': '2023-08-10', with the above record.
Actual record in Table: {'process_id': 1234, 'start_date': '2023-08-01', 'end_date': '2023-08-10', 'client_id': 'C-1'} // Viceversa if type B comes first.
```

I have implemented a Lambda function to process records whenever an object is created in the S3 bucket. Using boto3, I insert each record using `put_item`, employing a `ConditionExpression` as follows:

```py
condition_expression = 'attribute_not_exists(process_id)'
try:
    dynamodb.put_item(
        TableName='my-table',
        Item=item,
        ConditionExpression=condition_expression
    )
except dynamodb.exceptions.ConditionalCheckFailedException:
    if process_type == 'typeA':
        update_expression += ', start_date = :start_date_val'
        expression_attribute_values[':start_date_val'] = {'S': start_date}
    elif process_type == 'typeB':
        update_expression += ', end_date = :end_date_val'
        expression_attribute_values[':end_date_val'] = {'S': end_date}
    dynamodb.update_item(
        TableName='my-table',
        Key={'process_id': {'S': process_id}},
        UpdateExpression=update_expression,
        ExpressionAttributeValues=expression_attribute_values
    )
```

I use the `ConditionExpression` to check whether a record with a certain process ID already exists. If it doesn't, I insert the record. If it does, I update the dates accordingly.

However, I'm facing a performance issue. I have 50,000 records in a single file type. I attempted to use `batch_writer` for inserting and updating, but it doesn't support `put_item` with `ConditionExpression` or `update_item`.

I experimented with using `get_item` inside `batch_writer` to check if the record exists. If it doesn't, I use `put_item` to insert; if it does, I use `update_item` to update the date. However, using `get_item` seems to create individual calls for each item to check existence, and `update_item` is not supported by `batch_writer`. Is there a more optimized way to insert and update the records?

I've considered multithreading, but it still seems to result in individual insert requests to DynamoDB. Making 50,000+50,000 (type A + type B) records as individual requests for insert/update is a significant performance concern. Note that I will split the records into batches of 1000 to prevent Lambda timeouts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple schools of thought using DynamoDB schema design. My two cents are not to try updating the records or having a single table for both record types. To simplify your design, you can have two tables, one for each record type. When you need to have the `start-time` and the `end-time`, you can read the two records from the two tables and merge them in the client.

Answer (score -2):

Why not always using `update_item` ? it's NoSQL table so basically with `update_item` if attribute is there it will be updated if not it will be added  (Based on what I see from your example)

You maybe need to get the item from the database first so you're sure you're not deleting attributes.

This is also useful to check for more details: [Difference between DynamoDb PutItem vs UpdateItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667229/difference-between-dynamodb-putitem-vs-updateitem)